# Error in install sdk package in ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu

I want to install SDK in Android Studio but it shows this error

```
Warning: Failed to read or create install properties file.
    java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip': 
Read timed out, response: 200 OK
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Support Repository: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip': 
Read timed out, response: 200 OK.
```

Comment: The connection timed out. How many times have you tried to repeat this?

Comment: 1 day itryed without any result